# How to Use Embedding Projector with the latest version of TensorBoard ? (TF 2.0)

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorboard, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to build a model so as i can predict the gender from handwrting, so it's basically a binary classification problem, where lables are either 0 for men or 1 for women, and to have better control on how my model is behaving, i'm using TensorBoard Callback in *model.fil()*, however, i have two issues :

1- When i try to visualize my images in *image dash board* on TB, all i get is grey and black boxes even though i set *write_image* to True, how can this can be solved ? (code below and [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peNiz.png)) ;

2- When i try to use the Projector dash board, i visualise my data without lables, so all i can see is set of the data in 3 dimensions (PCA Set de 3), does anyone have an idea of how it can be solved ? ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKHMO.png))

```
import os
!rm -rf logs
log_dir = "./logs/1"
if not os.path.exists(log_dir):
  os.makedirs(log_dir)

tbCallBack = TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, 
                     histogram_freq=1, 
                     embeddings_freq=1, 
                     write_graph=False, 
                    write_images=True)
```